# Installing ImageMagick-devel fails on CentOS 8

Tags: centos, yum, imagemagick

I am trying to install ImageMagick-devel on my CentOS 8.0.1905, but I get the following error:

```
# yum install ImageMagick-devel
Last metadata expiration check: 2:58:25 ago on Mon 18 Nov 2019 06:58:06 PM EST.
Error:
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides jasper-devel needed by ImageMagick-devel-6.9.10.64-1.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides OpenEXR-devel needed by ImageMagick-devel-6.9.10.64-1.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides ghostscript-devel needed by ImageMagick-devel-6.9.10.64-1.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides lcms2-devel needed by ImageMagick-devel-6.9.10.64-1.el8.x86_64
```

any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Did you try to install Redmine? Than you may wait for version 4.1 which supports [minimagick](https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick) instead of rmagick. Described [here](https://www.redmine.org/issues/30492). With this you can use GraphicsMagick. Ignore this comment if your question does not relate to Redmine/rmagick.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to enable the PowerTools repo. As root:

```
yum config-manager --set-enabled PowerTools

dnf config-manager --set-enabled PowerTools
```

Either of those will work as `yum` redirects to `dnf`. All of those dependencies are provided by the PowerTools repo.

Comment: Any idea why my RHEL 8 system does not have PowerTools? I have epel repo but no PowerTools...

Comment: @robsch In RHEL 8, the repo is called CodeReady Builder. You can enable it with `subscription manager repos --enable codeready*` if it isn't already enabled.

Comment: Unfortunately this repo is not available. I don't know why...

Comment: This works for me in our AlmaLinux 8.5

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable powertools

```
sudo dnf install epel-release
sudo dnf config-manager --set-enabled powertools
```

For some

```
sudo dnf config-manager --set-enabled PowerTools
```

works, but it didn't work for me

After that it should install